# Data entity insert : An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know this question has been asked many times and after going through posts, I believe it has something to do with entity name, but I am completely new to data entity model and while trying to do a simple insert of a blog entry with blog details, I encountered this problem.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Source Error:

Line 365:    public void AddToblogs(blog blog)
Line 366:    {
Line 367:        base.AddObject("myblogs", blog);
Line 368:    }
Line 369:


Source File: C:\Inetpub\int422_113b16\webcontent\App_Code\blogModel.cs    Line: 367

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +9382923
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadRelationshipTypes() +661
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly() +17
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load() +25
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.Load() +4
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData) +160
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors) +166
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) +316
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection) +84
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly) +151
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity) +211
   blogEntities.AddToblogs(blog blog) in C:\Inetpub\int422_113b16\webcontent\App_Code\blogModel.cs:367
   BlogManager.BlogAdd(String title, String content, String userName) in C:\Inetpub\int422_113b16\webcontent\App_Code\BlogManager.cs:27
   Project_Admin_create_post.post_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Inetpub\int422_113b16\webcontent\Project\Admin\create-post.aspx.cs:25
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

BlogManager.cs

```
public class BlogManager
{
    private blogEntities _dbEnt = new blogEntities();

    public BlogManager()
    {
    }

    public void BlogAdd(int numId, string title, string content,string userName) 
    {

        blog newPost = new blog();
        newPost.blog_id = 1;
        newPost.blog_title = title;
        newPost.blog_content = content;
        newPost.date_created = null;
        newPost.user_name = userName;

        _dbEnt.AddTotheblog(newPost);
        _dbEnt.SaveChanges();
    }

    public class NameNotUniqueException : Exception
    {
        public NameNotUniqueException(string msg = "INT422 ERROR: matching data already exists")
            : base(msg)
        { }
    }
}
```

create-post.cs

```
public partial class Project_Admin_create_post : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            blogStatus.Text = "Your post is published";
            title.Enabled = false;
            content.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void post_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _userName = User.Identity.Name;

        BlogManager blogMgr = new BlogManager();
        blogMgr.BlogAdd(title.Text, content.Text, _userName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message is telling you the truth here.  You've previously, either in a child object in your blog post, or the blog post itself—added another entity of this type with the same entity key.

Is it possible that in one of your tables you've forgotten to set the identity key for your PK?  If so you might have a row with a key of 0, and subsequent inserts are conflicting with it.

Comment: Code is updated with the files I am using for insert. Let me know if you are seeking any other particular file

Comment: Everything is still same.. I have the PK, identity key & i added the number manually.. problem is still there

Comment: Are you using POCO?  when you say: `new blog()` - does the constructor create any child objects that might be screwing things up?

Comment: POCO? dont know.. just starting with data entity so ..
but if I dont create new object, I wont be able to pass the values.. is there any other way?

Comment: Did these classes get auto-created when you dragged your tables onto the designer, or did you write the classes by hand?

Comment: The blog class itself.  The class that's saved to the database.  Is that created by you by hand, or did the designer create it for you?

Comment: it was auto created with the entity cs file

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel - sorry I'm fresh out of ideas then.

Comment: its okay...I will find some way 
Thanks for all your help... I was able to realize lots of things that I ignored the first time :D

Comment: a question..recreating data entity
will there be a problem my data entity model name and model namespace are same?
both "BlogModel"?

Comment: Dropped the entity model & recreated it
& its working now O.O
Sorry for troubling you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(blog.EntityState==EntityState.Detached)
    base.AddObject("myblogs", blog);
```

Comment: What is blog PK? Are you forgot assign value to it?

Comment: its blog_id .. instead of auto assign..did it manually...
check the updated code of method BlogAdd(..)

Comment: Debug to sure BlogAdd method not called twice, Are you sure in context before add to context, not exist a blog with blog_id=1?

Comment: I wish I could.. School server doesnt allow it
but I just downloaded the whole site.. I am gonna debug on my local server